# How to know what is behind SQLiteCursor's address seen during debugging?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am debugging an application and when the `Cursor` retrieves a pointer from the database, I see something like this

[image]

How can I know what means the value behind `@`? How can I bind this address to the database value behind it?

Why do I need this? The app is behaving differently on 2 devices with 2 Android systems. I am cross debugging both and would like to know what the cursor returned on each device. For example, the value behind `@` on another device is a 4-digit integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is that of [`Object.toString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) and the number part is the `hashCode()`, not really an address.

For `Cursor` content debugging, have a look at [`DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursor(android.database.Cursor,%20java.io.PrintStream)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So simple. For even more simpler method, use this one: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursorToString(android.database.Cursor)

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to look up the SQL query to know what is going on, not this number. Just place you cursor on the Cursor and press Control-F1.

Comment: CTRL+F1 are details about the object. So I open them on `cursor` object, but what value should I look at? The closest I see is `/data/data/com.xyz.free/databases/xyz {b94daea0}`. Again, I have no idea what means the value inside the curvy brackets.